# How do I match and extract everything between spaces

Tags: c#, .net, regex

now I have got a long string like this

```
{"" ,"" ,"" ,"" } , {"" ,"" ,"" ,"" }
```

there could be anything in between `" "` even Unicode characters. I used something like this

```
string pattern = "\"([\u0000-\uffff]+)+\"";
```

but it just returns everything instead of return one by one.
I used Groups and Capture properties ,Capture Collection has info about everything matched but still I can't extract what I need. I need to extract everything in between `""` one by one. I don't need to extract the `{  }  " "` , just contents in between each `" "`.

So in my case there should be 8 groups should be returned, how can I do this?

Comment: What code are you using to process the Regex?

Comment: what do you mean by "what code"?

Comment: You have declared a variable `pattern`; what do you then do with it?

Comment: It's just a string typed pattern in which is used as a parameter for matches() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If pattern `","` is a reliable delimiter (cannot appear as text) and there are no empty spaces between curly brackets and quotation marks, you can use this approach:

```
        string input = @"{""a"",""b"","" my name is ""vul"" and it's nice "",""""},{"""","""","""",""""}";

        input = input
                .Replace("{", String.Empty)
                .Replace("}", String.Empty);

        var strings = input.Split(new string[] {@""","""}, StringSplitOptions.None);

        strings[0] = strings[0].TrimStart('"');
        strings[strings.Length - 1] = strings[strings.Length - 1].TrimEnd('"');
```

Comment: thanks for your effort. I have been thinking to give up using regex for this. cause it seems impossible to extract what I want just with regex.. I selected your answer as best I dunno it works or not but it opened my mind to solve this matter by using another method other than regex.. thanks anyway :)

Comment: I'm glad to help :) Regex is a powerful tool and it can do a lot but if input is consistently and predictably formatted `String` methods might be a simpler alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Use a non greedy capture

```
string pattern = "\"([\u0000-\uffff])*?\"";
```

And then use system linq to get your results...

```
var matches=Regex.Matches(input,pattern).OfType<Match>();
var results=matches.Select(g=>g.Groups[1].Value).ToArray();
```

results will now be a String[] containing all the matches

Comment: yeah it's pretty much close.. :P

Comment: @Vulcanoids, I've updated with out to obtain the values, why is it only close?

Comment: oops sorry I need to use .Net 2.. I meant if I use what you have made it's unable to return strings beyond " inside the " " think] if we have a string like this " my name is "vul" and it's nice " so it doesn't extract and it's nice part

Answer (score 0):

```
string pattern = "\"([\u0000-\uffff])+\"";
```

should do the trick.